# Gnome 3 fails to login, blank screen - Intel i915

Tags: gnome, intel-graphics

After an update with these packages:

```
x11proto-render-dev 0.11.1-2
x11proto-xinerama-dev (1.2.1-2)
x11proto-damage-dev (1.2.1-2
x11proto-core-dev (7.0.24-1)
nvidia-setting x11-dev  64 (1.6.1-1ubuntu1)
x11proto-kb-dev (1.0.6-2)
xtrans-dev (1.2.7-1) 
x11proto-fixes-dev (5.0-2ubuntu2)
nvidia-319-updates (319.60-0ubuntu1)
libxfixes-dev (5.0.1-1ubuntu1)
libxrandr-dev (1.4.0-1ubuntu2)
x11proto-xext-dev (7.2.1-1)
libxrender-dev (0.9.8-1)
x11proto-composite-dev (0.4.2-2)
libxinerama-dev (1.1.3-1)
libgtk2.0-dev (2.24.20-1ubuntu1)
libxcursor-dev (1.1.14-1)
```

My Gnome3 cannot work properly anymore. I can login successfully, but I just get a blank screen, and the cursor. I have installed Unity and KDE on the same machine. Unity has the same problem, *KDE works*.

### Hardware

My video card is an Intel i915:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor
Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

I have two monitors, one connected with VGA, the other one with DVI.

### Logs

Grepping the Xorg.log for errors, I found this:

```
[1817.840] (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
```

But I don't know if it could be related...

### Note

Yesterday I shutdown the system when it was in standby (I know standby is not working, so I had to do that).

What can I do to have my loved Gnome3 back and running? :)

Answer (score 1):

It was the nvidia driver. Installed to provide `opencv`...

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-319-updates
```

Fixed it. I can't understand why it installed that package in the first place. Anyway, now it works.